# How to test a http request in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to test a rootscope http request in my case

I have something like

mainCont file

```
$rootScope.testLoad = $http.get('/api/testapi/product');
```

TestCont file

```
$rootScope.testLoad.success(function(product){
    console.log(product)
})
```

Test file

```
describe('test', function () {
    var $httpBackend, $rootScope,  scope, mainCont, testCont;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        testCont = _$controller_('testCont', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        mainContr = _$controller_('mainCont', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    describe('test http request', function() {
        it('should check if the api is called', function() {       
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/testapi/product').respond(200);
            //I am not sure how to test the call in testCont file.  
        })
    })
});
```

I am not sure how to test the call in the testCont because when I run the test,
I got an error saying

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.testLoad.success')
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `testLoad` as a function, so you need to call it by adding parentheses. Change your code to

```
$rootScope.testLoad().success(function(product){
    console.log(product)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still getting the same error +1

Comment: I'm not familiar with your testing setup.  Are you sure you're injecting `$rootScope` into the mainCont and testCont files properly?

Comment: I would think so, I have another testing file that works with the setup like this

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` inside those files to ensure that you have access to `$rootScope` and `$rootScope.testLoad`?